# How to include base model property while getting child modes collections in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Model with the name "Parent" and a Model "Child" with its properties, there is a 1 to many relationship between "Parent" and "Child", Now asp.net MVC view I want to show Parent Mobile Number when viewing the child Record.
This is the Parent Model

```
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Forename { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Street Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [Display(Name = "Home Phone Number")]
        public string HomePhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Mobile Phone Number")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string MobilePhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Work Phone Number")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string WorkPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Child> Childrens { get; set;}

    }
```

and Child model is

```
 public class Child
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Forename { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "DOB")]
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string School { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "GP Name")]
        public string GPName { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [Display(Name = "GP Phone Number")]
        public string GPPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string AssignedTeam { get; set; }
        public virtual string ParentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }

    }
```

In the controller I am using this method

```
  public ActionResult Juniors(string Gender)
        {
            ViewBag.Gender = Gender;
            var juniors = db.Childrens.Where(c => c.Gender == Gender).ToList();
            return View(juniors);
        }
```

And The View is

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-responsive">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Forename)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Surname)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DOB)
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Parent / Guardian Mobile Number</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Parent / Guardian Email</label>
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Forename)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Surname)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DOB)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Parent.MobilePhoneNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Parent.User.Email)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("View Details", "Junior","Admin", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            }

        </table>
```

But the output not showing the Mobile Number and the Email
Here is the output
[image: Output]

Comment: try to include `parent`, like `var juniors = db.Childrens.Where(c => c.Gender == Gender).Include(x=>x.Parent).ToList();`

Comment: did but not worked

Comment: try to debug, and check the `Parent` for the children.

Comment: did but it return null

Comment: And the parentId is also null?should be a foreign key no?

Comment: No it is not null and yes it is the foreign key

Comment: why is not presented like the ``UserId`` with `[Key, ForeignKey("User")]` in the child entity?